# Changing color within a specific area with opencv using c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I would like to know if there's a simple way to change a color, say from a shade of grey to white, within an area of interest that would be determined from the image frame on the outside and a contour, returned from the opencv contour function. I mean, let's say I have an image with a black background and 2 circles, one inside the other, between the circles the color is a shade of grey, and inside the inner one is black. I found the outside circle contour, now I want to change the outside black for white.

Comment: Show us some of what you have tried.

Comment: I found the error, trying to solve it. My findContour is giving me the wrong contour with the THRESH_BINARY_INV flag on the image. When I use the TRESH_BINARY only gives me the right contour, but I would have to merge this contour with the frame  box, because my area of interest is the area between the frame and the contour.

Comment: is there a way to make a intersection of 2 contours and the new contour be the contour of the intersected area?

Comment: Now I've got 2 images that I wanted to do a logical and to get only the pixels that are the same in both images. How can I do that?

Comment: I got it, now. my bitwise was returning an error because of a cvt convertion. What I did was to do the TRESH_BINARY, after findContours I did drawContour and set to CV_FILLED my interior, than I did a bitwise_or with the images to get what I wanted.

Comment: You can answer and accept your own answer. A comment isn't a place for answers.